# Error: could not build wheels for numpy (or any other modules)

Tags: pip, python-module, termux, python-3.11

Unable to install any python modules using 'pip install <module_name>' in termux.

Hey community, I'm using termux to code and run python since I don't have a laptop. In order to run some high end python programs, i need to install modules. So I decided to start installing numpy module. But there occurs this wierd error which is so annoying.[error: could not build wheels for numpy] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqIC0.jpg)

I've also tried downgrading python from 3.11 to 3.10.9 but that didn't help.

So I finally came here seeking help from community.

Please help.

Comment: Hello. Did you google the error messages? A quick google gave 3 results already of people having a similar problem: https://superuser.com/questions/1724176/why-pip-throwing-an-error-when-installing-numpy-in-termux https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/10808 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004464/error-trying-to-install-numpy

Answer (score 0):

#### [v-ops] - `pkg install python-numpy`

##### [More Info](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Python#Python_module_installation_tips_and_tricks) - Package Management